# Preload and auto play Vimeo videos in viewport AND fade cover image

Tags: jquery, video, vimeo, autoplay, froogaloop

I am trying to use the Vimeo API with froogaloop2 to autoplay several embedded iframe videos on the page when scrolled into viewport.  I want to make sure the videos are loaded before the cover image is removed to avoid a black loading screen. I can't seem to make the `player.addEvent('playprogress', onPlayProgress)` callback work.

HTML example of video embed used 4 to 6 times on same page:

```
<div class="wpb_video_wrapper">
<img class="vimeo-cover" width="100%" height="100%" src="myimageurl">
<iframe class="videoplayer" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/myvideourl?api=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;background=1&amp;mute=0&amp;loop=0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Partially working JS:

```
<script src='https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// check device, ignore mobile devices

window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if (!mobilecheck()) {

    console.log("not mobile device");

    // setup variables

    var iframe;
    var player;
    var player_cover;

    $('iframe.videoplayer[src*="vimeo.com"]').each(function () {

      iframe = $(this)[0];
      player = $f(iframe);
      player_cover = $(this).parent().children('.vimeo-cover');

      // verify cover image is stored, this is the part that doesn't work
      // console.log(player_cover); 

      // check if videos "ready"
      player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        console.log("video ready");
        // run callback function when video loaded AND playing
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
      });

      // function to hide cover image (not working with player_cover var)
      function onPlayProgress(data)  {
          console.log(video loaded, playing);
          // $('.vimeo-cover').delay(3000).fadeOut(); WANT THIS TO WORK
          // player_cover.delay(2000).fadeOut(); WANT THIS TO WORK
          console.log("video loaded, cover faded");
      };

      // if video in viewport, play video otherwise pause
      if ($(this).is(':in-viewport')) {
        $f(this).api('play');
        console.log("play vimeo video");
        // player_cover.delay(2000).fadeOut(); THIS WORKS - TIMED WORKAROUND
        // console.log("fade cover"); THIS WORKS - TIMED WORKAROUND
      } else {
        $f(this).api('pause');
        console.log("pause vimeo video");
      }

    });

    // during scrolling AND video in viewport, play video otherwise pause
    $( window ).scroll(function() {

      $('iframe.videoplayer[src*="vimeo.com"]').each(function () {

        player_cover = $(this).parent().children('.vimeo-cover');

        // console.log(player_cover);

        player.addEvent('ready', function() {
          player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
        });

        function onPlayProgress(data)  {
          console.log("video loaded, playing");
          // player_cover.delay(3000).fadeOut(); WANT THIS TO WORK
          // console.log("video loaded, cover faded"); WANT THIS TO WORK
        };

        if ($(this).is(':in-viewport')) {
          $f(this).api('play');
          console.log("play vimeo video");
          // player_cover.delay(2000).fadeOut(); THIS WORKS - TIMED WORKAROUND
          // console.log("fade cover"); THIS WORK - TIMED WORKAROUND
        } else {
          $f(this).api('pause');
          console.log("pause vimeo video");
        }
      });
    });

  }
});
</script>
```